# Is Mathematics a branch of "Natural Science"?

Tags: soft-question, career-development

Actually, I was seeking for top universities, which has mathematics depart, in Pakistan and I found one, namely Quaid-i-Azam University. Which is known for its Education in "Natural Science". Then I apprehend what is Natural Science. So, I started to read the article on Wikipedia about it but I didn't find mathematics in their context. Is not mathematics a branch of "Natural Science"?

Comment: Since mathematics relies not on experiments and construction of imperfect models to approximate universal truths but instead pure logic, mathematics is really a science of its own kind and not a natural science. Some say that is is a "Geisteswissenschaft", so more in a category with philosophy, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is relevant but was not closed at all.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649408/is-computer-science-a-branch-of-mathematics

Comment: @SMF: There is less difference between mathematics and physical sciences than you say. Every time you search for examples and counterexamples to statements, you are doing so to test hypotheses on what is or is not true. The difference between physics and mathematics is not in whether we experiment, but in how the outcomes of our experiments are determined: in physics the outcome is determined by physical reality; in mathematics by pure logic.

Comment: @LeeMosher Then maybe the difference between math and physics isn't whether you preform experiments, but whether you admit to having done so in written work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In university departments, mathematics is usually grouped with the physical or natural sciences. The physical or natural sciences usually include physics, chemistry, mathematics, statistics, computer science, etc.

Comment: Are you sure??? It's really important for me to know..

Comment: @SufyanNaeem At least that's how it is in the US and Western Europe. All of these fields share the application of the scientific method.

Comment: Yes. That's a good point that they all share the application of the scientific methods.

Comment: As opposed to life sciences?